# React native app crashes in version Android 11

Tags: react-native, react-redux, android-11

from firebase crashlytics the error logs are   okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextProxy (RouteSelector.java:129)

Answer (score 1):

add in the file **android/app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
     implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.9.3"))
}
```

solution from : https://github.com/tinycreative/react-native-intercom/issues/441#issuecomment-852500812